# C++ atomic load ordering efficiency

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have a memory variable that is updated in thread A and read in other threads. The reader only cares if the value is non-zero.  I am guaranteed that once the value is incremented, it never goes back to zero.
Does it make sense to optimize as below?
In other words, on the reader side, I dont need "fence" once I got my condition satisfied.

```
std::atomic<int> counter;

writer:
increment()
{ 
    counter.store(counter+1, std:memory_order_release)
}

reader:
iszero()
{
    if (counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) > 0) return false;
    // memory fence only if condition not yet reached
    return (counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0);
}
```

Comment: The counter could wrap around back to zero.

Comment: In reader::iszero() have a thread-local boolean and set it to true teh first time you get a non-zero value back from the counter. If that's true, immediately return false. Only if it's still false, check the counter.

Comment: How often is reader called? This seems like premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you've not actually tried using the default (sequentially consistent) atomics, measured the performance of your app, profiled it, and shown observed them causing a performance problem, I'd suggest turning back now.

However, if you really do need to start reasoning about relaxed atomics...

---

That is not guaranteed to do what you expect, although it will almost certainly work on x86.

I'm guessing that you're using this to guard the publication of some other non-atomic data.

In that case, you need the guarantee that **if** you read a non-zero value in the reader thread, **then** various other side-effects to non-atomic memory locations (i.e. initializing the data you're publishing) that you made in the writer thread prior to the store will be visible to the reader thread.

Reading non-zero with `std::memory_order_relaxed` does not *synchronize with* the `std::memory_order_release` store, so your code above does not have this guarantee.

To get the behaviour I've described, you need to use `std::memory_order_acquire`. If you're on x86, then acquire doesn't produce any memory fence instructions, so the only way it will differ in  performance from `memory_order_relaxed` is via preventing some compiler optimizations.

Comment: First, in my case, I care about the non-atmoic locations only when I care about the new non-zero value of the atomic location.  I checked the x86 instructions - youre right that there seems to be no difference between acquire and relaxed - both use mov. I only require the guarantee that all stores are seen in sequence. I was hoping I could get a lighter instruction-set with release, seems its not the case.